# rails 4 acts-as-taggable-on gem rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

We keep encountering a build error with the  [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem that has proven to be quite elusive:

```
== 20140517050649 ActsAsTaggableOnMigration: migrating ========================
-- create_table(:tags)
   -> 0.0057s
-- create_table(:taggings)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "taggings" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "taggings" ("id" serial primary key, "tag_id" integer, "taggable_id" integer, "taggable_type" character varying(255), "tagger_id" integer, "tagger_type" character varying(255), "context" character varying(128), "created_at" timestamp) /home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/home/apps/api/releases/20141107204423/db/migrate/20140517050649_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:8:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "taggings" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "taggings" ("id" serial primary key, "tag_id" integer, "taggable_id" integer, "taggable_type" character varying(255), "tagger_id" integer, "tagger_type" character varying(255), "context" character varying(128), "created_at" timestamp)
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/home/apps/api/releases/20141107204423/db/migrate/20140517050649_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:8:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "taggings" already exists
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/home/apps/api/releases/20141107204423/db/migrate/20140517050649_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb:8:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/apps/api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
deploy@apistaging:/home/apps/api/current$
```

This issue forces me to drop the table, then re-run rake db:migrate.  This was not a huge pain until I tried using PG commands to back up and restore the db.  The same error popped up there.

Has anyone come across this issue?

*Update*

I should note, this only occurs on the server, not local.

Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.1

[github acts-as-taggable-on issue](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/609)

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward -- your database (for some reason) already has a "taggings" table.  Are you manually creating a taggings table in another migration?

Comment: @JTG no, I have double checked all of the migrations + this does not occur locally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get around this error by changing the gem migrations to:

```
# This migration comes from acts_as_taggable_on_engine (originally 1)
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table 'tags' unless !ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'tags'

    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :tags
  end
end
```

And...

```
# This migration comes from acts_as_taggable_on_engine (originally 1)
class CreateTaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table 'taggings' unless !ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'taggings'

    create_table :taggings do |t|
      t.references :tag

      # You should make sure that the column created is
      # long enough to store the required class names.
      t.references :taggable, :polymorphic => true
      t.references :tagger, :polymorphic => true

      # Limit is created to prevent MySQL error on index
      # length for MyISAM table type: http://bit.ly/vgW2Ql
      t.string :context, :limit => 128

      t.datetime :created_at
    end

    add_index :taggings, :tag_id
    add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :taggings
  end
end
```

You will notice I am checking to see if the table exists, and I am deleting it beforehand, then recreating it. [ActiveRecordMigration-Safe-Table-DROPs](http://coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/ActiveRecordMigration-Safe-Table-DROPs)

**UPDATED FIX**

As it turns out, for whatever reason there was a copy of the taggings table inside our Postgres `template 1` database.  Whenever our database was created it used the template database and created the problem behind the scenes. What a mess.